# Why is (=<<) id = join in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
id :: a -> a
join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

So shouldn't,

```
(=<<) id
```

give an error because,

```
id :: a -> a
```

and not,

```
id :: a -> m a
```

Doesn't (=<<) expect,

```
(something -> m anything)
```

as its first argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`m a' -> m a'` is also a kind of `a -> a`, so we can have

```
      id ::  m a' -> m a'                        -- a = m a'
   (=<<) :: (m a' -> m a') -> m (m a') -> m a'   -- a = m a', b = a'

(=<<) id ::                   m (m a') -> m a'
```

Comment: ooo! got it!

    (=<<) :: (m a' -> m a') -> m (m a') -> m a'   -- a = m a', b = a'

did it for me. a can be m a', all that is necessary is one get back anything wrapped in m. Thanks mate!

Comment: @louzer Exactly.  You can consider 1 layer of `m` to be a stable point of a monad. You can always join 2 or more layers of `m` into 1 layer using `join`, and you can always lift 0 layers of `m` into 1 layer using `return`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: it does get a bit more complicated when you have something like `m (n (m a))` though.

Comment: @BenMillwood and in those cases, `sequenceA` (a kind of generalized `transpose`) from `Data.Traversable` can swap the outer `m` and `n` or the inner `n` and `m` so that `join` can then apply.

Comment: @Conal: sure, you can do that when the types involved are in the right classes, but it's not as simple as "if you have two monad type constructors, just join them". Sometimes, of course, `IO (IO a)` actually *is* the type you want.

Comment: @BenMillwood Of course, if you want the type constructors uncollapsed, just don't `join` them. What was the "does get a bit more complicated" you had in mind?

Comment: @Conal: I felt that Gabriel's comment implied that monads need only appear once in your type, or at least only once in any composition of types, and I was trying to come up with examples where that was not the case (either because you couldn't join, or because you didn't want to).